# Problem uploading to FTP using S7FTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ftp

I'm trying to use S7FTPRequest to upload files to an FTP server:

```
S7FTPRequest *ftp = [[S7FTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://ftp.abc.com/aaa/files/"]       
toUploadFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"info" ofType:@"plist"]];

  ftp.username = @"name";
  ftp.password = @"pass";
  ftp.directoryName = @"/aaa/files/";
  ftp.delegate = self;
  ftp.filePath = @"/users/meir/Stuart-Highway.jpg";
  ftp.didFinishSelector = @selector(uploadFinished:);
  ftp.didFailSelector = @selector(uploadFailed:);
  ftp.willStartSelector = @selector(uploadWillStart:);
  ftp.didChangeStatusSelector = @selector(requestStatusChanged:);
  ftp.bytesWrittenSelector = @selector(uploadBytesWritten:);

  [ftp startRequest];
```

After that, I am getting the message (in console):
*Will transfer 44799 bytes*.

And it does nothing. After a while I am getting a timeout message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.
That code is perfect. You have to keep the RunLoop running in order to run the loop.

Comment: can you clarify a little more  - I am having this same problem.

Comment: S7FTPRequest is now called SCRFTPRequest and located here https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest

Comment: That's not the way to answer a question. You must indicate the error in code.